# Can stateless LSTM recognize sub-sequences?

Tags: lstm, keras

Suppose I want to recognize a sequence like `010` but I don't know it's length, so I arbitrarily fed my network with sequences of length 7. The sequence I'm looking for turns out to be a sub-sequence in some of the data-points.

The input is a sequence 7 elements long, the output is one-hot vector which says which sequence occurred.

```
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0] -> [1,0,0] # present
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0] -> [1,0,0] # present
[0,0,1,2,0,0,0] -> [0,1,0] # absent
```

Is stateless LSTM capable of recognizing my sub-sequence, if it occurs in a different location withing the fed sequence?

```
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0] -> [1,0,0] # ? the network has never seen such a sequence
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is capable.

Keep in mind that LSTMs have a memory which stretches across the entire input sequence, so it would be able to learn such a pattern. Making LSTMs "stateful" is a bit of a hack to make memory sort-of work *across* multiple sequences. However, that isn't to say that a vanilla "stateless" LSTM doesn't have a state -- it very much does.